# Pattern matching efficiency in shell script

Tags: performance, shell, scripting, pattern-matching, vi

I have a directory MAIN_DIR with 30 sub-directories each containing roughly 30,000 files. I want to go through each directory in MAIN_DIR and copy every 10th file that matches a certain pattern to another location. This is my script:

```
cd /path/MAIN_DIR
num=0
for dir in *; do

     cd $dir
     for f in `find . -name \*XYZ*`; do
          if [ `expr $num % 10` -eq 0 ]; then
              cp $f /new/location/new_dir/$f
          fi
          num=$((num+1))
     done
     cd ..

done
```

It works as intended, the problem is it is horrendously slow, taking about 8 hours to run through all 30 directories. I know that both pattern matching and the modulo operation are rather slow, but 8 hours seems a bit high. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of this script?

Comment: Many things but start with not using `expr` (which requires a sub-shell and is non-standard and largely obsolete) and just use shell arithmetic `$(( num % 10 )). Also you can avoid using `\[`/`test` if you are checking `== 0` and just use `if ! (( num % 10 )); then` (also shell arithmetic) since as the man page says "if the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1". That said I think this question is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than here as the code works.

Comment: Also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than here as the code works.

Comment: Try commenting out the line starting `cp $f ...` and see how long it takes to run - then you will know if the issue is copying the files or creating the million processes needed to see if you are on the tenth file.

Answer (score 1):

Your script takes about 1 minute per directory of 30,000 files on my machine - without copying anything but just choosing the files. So I guess around 30 minutes of your 8+ hours is spent inefficiently choosing them, so the actual problem is probably the copying.

You can replace your script with something like this to determine the files to copy, but it will still take 7+ hours unless you do the copying in parallel and your network/drives can provide that bandwidth.

```
find . -type f -name ... | awk '(FNR%10)==0'
```

That runs in 24 seconds for all 1 million files.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `ash` or `dash` you may not be able to improve this (I'm not certain).

If you're using ksh or bash, replace

```
if [ `expr $num % 10` -eq 0 ]; then
```

with

```
if (( $num % 10 )) ; then
```

This way, you will using internal evaluations built into the shell and avoid creating sub processes.

-- Also, based on comments above, I include these sample evaluations illustrating the use of the `%` mod operator:

```
 num=9;  if (( $num % 10 )) ; then echo not 10 ; else echo num%10 ; fi
    not a 10
 num=10 ;-if (( $num % 10 )) ; then echo not 10 ; else echo num%10 ; fi
    num%10
 num=20 ;-if (( $num % 10 )) ; then echo not 10 ; else echo num%10 ; fi
    num%10
 num=111;  if (( $num % 10 )) ; then echo not 10 ; else echo num%10 ; fi
    not a 10
```

---

I would (for my own info) add `time` to the front of the `cp` cmd, i.e.

```
time cp $f /new/location/new_dir/$f
```

to see the individual cost of each file being copied. If you are copying across a slow network, or from one place on a drive to another on the same drive, there's probably not much you can do to speed that up.

IHTH

Comment: `((` is not POSIX, but `if test "$(( $num % 10 )) -eq 0` will work without invoking any subshells or child processes.

Comment: @chepner : Arg, more POSIXisms! ;-) ... OK, good to know and if OP needs POSIX compliance, then `if test ..` is the right answer. But are you saying the `if (( .. ))` does invoke a subshell? Its my understanding (at least for ksh) that the processing is internal to the shell. Thanks for the comment, Good luck to all.

Comment: No, `((...))` is fine; as the built-in arithmetic *statement*, it does what you want. For POSIX compliance, you need to embed the arithmetic *expression* `$(( ... ))` into another command to achieve the same effect. (Although technically, nothing in POSIX requires `test` to be a built-in command, just available, but there's not much you can do about that.)